# How to stop foreach loop in a given state

Tags: c#

```
foreach (String host   in hostArray)
{
    string s1 = hostArray[t];
    string s2 = branchArray[t];
    string con_msg;
    t=t+1;
    TcpClient socketForServer;
    try
    {
        socketForServer = new TcpClient(s1, 10);
        con_msg="Connected";
    }
    catch
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        item.Text = (s2);
        item.SubItems.Add(s1);
        item.SubItems.Add("Not found");
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        con_msg = "Not connected";
        // I want to exit this round in here and and start next round  how to do it 
    }

    NetworkStream networkStream = socketForServer.GetStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader streamReader =  new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);
    System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter =new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
    //code
}
```

I want to exit current round in catch and start next round. how to do it. I don't want to exit foreach loop , i just want to exit from current round and start next round

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in Items)
{           
  try
  {
    //Exception
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    continue;//Will move to next item of "Items" of FOREACH LOOP
  }

  int a = 1 + 1;//If exception gets this line will not execute
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

use `continue` to do that. See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The **continue** statement passes control to the next iteration of the enclosing iteration statement in which it appears.

Here is how **continue** statement would look like in your code:

```
foreach (String host   in hostArray)
{
    string s1 = hostArray[t];
    string s2 = branchArray[t];
    string con_msg;
    t=t+1;
    TcpClient socketForServer;
    try
    {
        socketForServer = new TcpClient(s1, 10);
        con_msg="Connected";
    }
    catch
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        item.Text = (s2);
        item.SubItems.Add(s1);
        item.SubItems.Add("Not found");
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        con_msg = "Not connected";

        continue;
    }

    NetworkStream networkStream = socketForServer.GetStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader streamReader =  new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);
    System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter =new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
    //code
}
```

The **goto** statement transfers the program control directly to a labeled statement.

Here is how **goto** statement would look like in your code:

```
foreach (String host   in hostArray)
{
    string s1 = hostArray[t];
    string s2 = branchArray[t];
    string con_msg;
    t=t+1;
    TcpClient socketForServer;
    try
    {
        socketForServer = new TcpClient(s1, 10);
        con_msg="Connected";
    }
    catch
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        item.Text = (s2);
        item.SubItems.Add(s1);
        item.SubItems.Add("Not found");
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        con_msg = "Not connected";

        goto ErrorOccured;
    }

    NetworkStream networkStream = socketForServer.GetStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader streamReader =  new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);
    System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter =new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
    //code

    ErrorOccured:
    Console.WriteLine("Do something else...");
}
```

Comment: You would have to have another label in the `goto` example, because `ErrorOccured` will execute when the `//code` is done.

Comment: I'm not sure that using a `goto` is the best choice. Perhaps using an error flag (`bool`) would be a better choice and then an `if (flag)` at the end to choose the correct code path.

Comment: @Default, yep, that's the point of goto statement.. i just provided 2 possible solutions. In his case "continue" statement is more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

use `continue` to exit from current round just before finishing the catch...
By using the `continue` statement in catch, the statements between continue and the end of the foreach body should be skip. as example ... it is just like HABJAN gave..

```
    foreach (String host   in hostArray){

        string s1 = hostArray[t];
        string s2 = branchArray[t];
        string con_msg;
        t=t+1;
        TcpClient socketForServer;

       try{
           socketForServer = new TcpClient(s1, 10);
           con_msg="Connected";
       }
       catch{
           ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
           item.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
           item.Text = (s2);
           item.SubItems.Add(s1);
           item.SubItems.Add("Not found");
           listView1.Items.Add(item);
           con_msg = "Not connected";

           continue;
       }

       NetworkStream networkStream = socketForServer.GetStream();
       System.IO.StreamReader streamReader =  new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);
       System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter =new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
       // code
   }
```